# name error while trying to refering the "view " method in same class

Tags: python-3.x, oop

```py
class Solution:
    def bottomView(self, root):
        # code here
        v={0:root}
        self.View(root,v,0)
        return [ d for i,d in v.items()]
    def View(self,root,v,d):
        v[d]=root.data
        if root.left:
            view(self,root.left,v,d-1)
        if root.right:
            view(self,root.right,v,d+1)
```

//error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/f94469e221bb681a04f81ecf69c00640.py", line 103, in 
res = ob.bottomView(root)
File "/home/f94469e221bb681a04f81ecf69c00640.py", line 7, in bottomView
self.View(root,v,0)
File "/home/f94469e221bb681a04f81ecf69c00640.py", line 12, in View
view(self,root.left,v,d-1)
NameError: name 'view' is not defined